# Is exporting a function just for testing considered a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, design-patterns

I have this question especially after reading the official redux documentation on testing React components:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md

> In order to be able to test the App component itself without having to deal with the decorator, we recommend you to also export the undecorated component

Even the famous https://www.reactboilerplate.com/ exports named unconnected components just to be able to test them without mocking a store.

But isn't it considered bad to export something just so it makes things easier to test?

There might be cases when a developer makes the wrong import and introduces a bug just because there are two things exported from a file.

So, the question essentially is:

Can we make changes to the actual code to make testing easier?

Although this question is specific to React, would be great to know if any other languages or frameworks have similar problems and how they are dealt with.

Comment: In my opinion the API should have access to the functionality we want to test. If there is anything we have to and cannot test consider breaking it down to smaller components and test them. So changes to the code should not come solely for testing purposes. (Some design choices can be made to make testing easier but those usually involve other benefits as well)

Comment: you can always make a conditional export based on `process.NODE_ENV`. so when your env is development/testing, you export additional, raw component used in tests and if env is production then your additional export is null or empty object.

Comment: also, maybe good to be noted: unit testing connected component is not unit testing anymore since you’re testing at least 2 things in one test: component, store, reducer, actions...

Comment: Can you give an example of how a conditional export would work? @deezg

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed take a look at my answer with example, please.

Comment: `But isn't it considered bad to export something just so it makes things easier to test?` -- No. It is often considered good practice. There is even a name for this in engineering: Design for Testability

Comment: Nice, I've never knew there's such a thing like "Design for Testability"

Comment: I think it's still bad practice. Design for Testability is a good thing, but that doesn't mean that ANY design for testing is good. Imagine you make a pad lock with complicated internals. You could "design it for testability" by making easy to remove covers so anyone can access the internals. Would that be a good thing? A design is only good when it doesn't compromise other design intents, like reducing surface area.

Answer (score 4):

you can always do conditional export based on your environment.

something like:

```
export default connect(mstp, mdtp)(component1);

export let tests = {
  component1,
  component2,
  ...
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !==   "test") {
  tests = undefined;
}
```

and then in your test file you do

```
import { tests} from ".";
const { component1, component2 } = tests;
//now test unconnected components
```